# CMD does not autoclose using /C

Tags: excel, vba, cmd

I have the following vba code in a module:

```
Sub Test()
 Dim strCMD As String
 strCMD = "CMD /C ECHO wait... & PING 10.0.0.0 -n 1 -w 5000 >NUL & Excel.exe " & Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.FullName & Chr(34)
 Shell strCMD, vbNormalFocus
 Application.Quit
End Sub
```

The code works fine: It reopens the workbook succesfully. The problem is that the `cmd` window does not autoclose after reopening the workbook (I want it to autoclose after reopening the workbook).

I assigned the code to a button inserted in the workbook sheet.
I have windows 10 and Excel 2013.

I tried adding `& " & EXIT"` at the end of the `strCMD` string with no success.

Note: The cmd window closes when I click in the **close button** of the reopened workbook.

Comment: Change `Excel.exe` to `Start Excel.exe`.

Comment: @Compo It worked! Thank you. Can you explain why it happens with `Excel.exe` and with `Start Excel.exe` not?

Comment: Simply that the batch file will wait for the excel executable to be closed before continuing. Using start runs it as a seperate process, and continues the batch file.